# Class diagramm from Android project using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, uml, class-diagram

I want to create a class diagramm from an Android project. I wrote this peoject in Java code using Eclipse. I'm using  objectaid plugin in eclipse but there aren't associations in my class diagramm. I see classes, attributes,methods but I don't see the associations between different activities.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this operation using this tool or another ones.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [this](http://fuzz-box.blogspot.de/2012/09/how-to-generate-uml-diagrams-from-java.html)
.

I hope that helped.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/259228: "_..links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.._"